# How to parallelize function with MPI c++

Tags: c++, function, parallel-processing, mpi

i'm new on MPI and after studying the basics, still I do not understand how I could leverage mpi for a parallel execution of two function, one for the first part of elements and second for the second part. 
For example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < argc/2; i++){
  function(el[i]);
 }

for(int i = 0; i < argc-1; i++){
  function(el[i]);
 }
```

How i can use MPI_Send, MPI_recv ecc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MPI is a multiprocessor library, not a multithreading one. Consequently the data are splitted and cannot be seen as a single array on which the cores can process a part of it.

Here, to process the data, each core need to have an array which contains half the data. With MPI_SEND and MPI_RECV, it will look something like this

```
Get rank and number of proc
Create subarray
Pass parts of initial array from proc 0 to other procs (With MPI_SEND for proc 0 and MPI_RECV for others)
Each proc do the calculation 
Reunite the results with a new set of send/recv
```

After, it exists too some functions to make the data spreading and reunificating easier

Good Luck

Comment: I have only one question, what do you mean with :Reunite the results with a new set of send/recv

Comment: It depends of your results, but if the function modify your elements and you need one processor which know all the results, then you need a result tab which reunite all the arrays.
If you doesn't need that, you don't need to gather the results. But in a general way, a processor need to know all the results, and you need a reunification step.